# Exposing the state of a react widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a react UI widget thats let's the user select a number of different times and dates. The user's current selection is stored in the state of a top level component, `DateTimePicker`. I then have a widget wrapper like so:

```
import ...

export default {
  new: (args) => {

    const store = {
      reactElement: <DateTimePicker
          startDate={args.startDate}
          endDate={args.endDate}
      />
    };

    return {
      getState: () => {
        return store.reactElement.getState(); // DOESN'T WORK
      },
      render: (selector) => {
        ReactDOM.render(store.reactElement, document.querySelector(selector));
      }
    };
  }
};
```

I want to add a validation to make sure that at least X days/times are selected, but this validation needs to be implemented outside of the widget.

For this, I'll need someway of asking the widget of it 's state. i.e. what has the user selected? Although it seems like the state of the class is not part of the public api of a react component.

How can I acess the state, or is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: There are a lot of problems here.  `getState` doesn't work because your store isn't a redux store.  It's just an object that doesn't implement a `getState` function.  Are you trying to work with redux?  Why are you exporting an object instead of a React class?

Comment: I'm not trying to work with Redux. I perhaps explained it poorly, but `getState` is just a method I would like to have on `DateTimePicker` that returns the state, or at least part of it. I'm exporting an object, not a react class, so I can encapsulate the `ReactDOM.render` call.

Comment: Ok, following you now... where does DateTimePicker come from?  Is there an api from a package you can look at?  Or are you making your own component here?  If that's the case, please add the code for that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to doing things imperatively from the parent to the child usually involves getting a `ref` to the child component.  Something along these lines:

```
export default {
  new: (args) => {
    let myRef = React.createRef();
    const store = {
      reactElement: <DateTimePicker
          ref={myRef}
          startDate={args.startDate}
          endDate={args.endDate}
      />
    };

    return {
      getState: () => {
        return myRef.current.getState(); 
      },
      render: (selector) => {
        ReactDOM.render(store.reactElement, document.querySelector(selector));
      }
    };
  }
};
```

With `ref={myRef}` added as a prop, whenever `DateTimePicker` gets mounted, it will assign a reference to the mounted component to `myRef.current`.  You can then use that reference to interact directly with the most recently mounted component.